# AudioManager Context, Android Kotlin Fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

how i can create AudioManager in Fragment ? I use this and it is not work.

```
val audioManager: AudioManager = getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
```

Thanks all!

Answer (score 1):

```
        val audioManager = requireContext().getSystemService(AudioManager::class.java)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Code-only answers are less useful than ones that explain how the code solves the problem. Especially when you are answering your own question, it helps future readers to understand how you resolved your problem.

Comment: Please add an explanation to improve the insight and give the OP some more information

Comment: Where does this code go? Isn't this supposed to be Kotlin, if so why class.java?  
Also, when I use this I get No value passed for parameter 'provider' at the ( )